# Cuando aplico calor a un LM35 la temperatura decrementa

Tags: arduino

He tenido un problema con el sensor LM35 en Arduino. La temperatura marcaba 30°, luego 29° e iba bajando hasta llegar a 0° luego subía y bajaba.

De algún modo ya ahora se mantiene estable en 24 y 25 grados celsius, sin embargo al momento de aplicar calor con algún encendedor, la temperatura en lugar de subir comienza a bajar de manera acelerada.

Compré tres sensores LM35 y con todos pasa exactamente lo mismo (cabe aclarar que me costo cada uno $35 mexicanos o 1.25$ dólares).

He probado con una gran cantidad de código pero en todos sucede lo mismo. Actualmente utilizo el siguiente código:

```
const int sensorPin= A0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int value = analogRead(sensorPin);
  float millivolts = (value / 1023.0) * 5000;
  float celsius = millivolts / 10; 
  Serial.print(celsius);
  Serial.println(" C");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Y el circuito como lo tengo conectado está de la siguiente forma:
[image: Circuito]

Y éstos son los valores como se encuentran y después como comienza a bajar al momento de aplicar calor.

[image: Valores]

Comment: ¿Podrías sacar una foto en la que se vea el modelo exacto del dispositivo o la página donde lo compraste? También vendría bien foto del montaje real para comprobar que las conexiones `+` y `-` son correctas (entre otras).

Comment: Aquí anexo las imagenes de como lo tengo montado y una última donde se muestra el sensor.
https://imgur.com/a/GEczlSX

Comment: No se ve bien el modelo del componente, las conexiones parecen correctas. ¿Has medido voltajes con un polímetro para comprobar que llegan 5v y el voltaje que se entrega en la patilla central? Es importante comprobar si se trata de un LM35 u otro "compatible" porque las características podrían variar. Yo, además, comprobaría su funcionamiento en vacío: sin conectar la patilla central al arduino y/o con alimentación externa (es muy versátil porque funciona desde apenas 4v hasta más de 20v).

Comment: Aquí esta una foto un poco más clara https://imgur.com/a/l9D1LXF no he hecho aun la prueba del polímetro, es posible realizar la prueba entonces conectado el LM35 a una fuente externa (que sería una pila de 9V) y la pata central de datos al arduino?. Supongo que para eso tendría que cambiar el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¡Solucionado!**

Compré otro LM35 y se solucionó el problema ya que el circuito, las conexiones y el código estaba bien.

Por lo que la conclusión es que había comprado con anterioridad dispositivos defectuosos.

Comment: Enhorabuena :) o eran defectuosos, o eran otros componentes diferentes. Por desgracia no pude leer el modelo a partir de las fotos que compartiste, pero me alegra que encontraras el problema.